# How to interpret this PHP statement?

Tags: php

I would like to know what kind of variable is `$firstLine` in the following php code line. Is it a pointer or what ?

```
$firstLine=$myMovie->add($myShape1);
```

Thanks

OK here is the complete code:

```
  <html>
 <body>
  <? 
   $myShape1=new SWFShape(); 

   $myShape1->setLine(5,0,0,255); 

    $myShape1->drawLine(440,0); 

   $myMovie=new SWFMovie(); 

   $myMovie->setDimension(460,80); 
   $myMovie->setBackground(255,0,0); 

   $firstLine=$myMovie->add($myShape1); 
   $firstLine->moveTo(10,10); 

    $secondLine=$myMovie->add($myShape1); 
   $secondLine->moveTo(10,70); 

   $myMovie->save("lesson2.swf"); 

  ?> 

   <OBJECT classid="clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000"    codebase="http://active.macromedia.com/flash2/cabs/swflash.cab#version=4,0,0,0" ID=objects        WIDTH=460 HEIGHT=80>
   <PARAM NAME=movie VALUE="lesson2.swf">
    <EMBED src="lesson2.swf" WIDTH=460 HEIGHT=80 TYPE="application/x-shockwave-flash"       PLUGINSPAGE="http://www.macromedia.com/shockwave/download /index.cgi?P1_Prod_Version=ShockwaveFlash">
```

```
       </body>
       </html>
```

Comment: it depends on `$myMovie->add()`. `gettype()` and `getclass()` functions would help.

Answer (score 1):

Depends what **add** function returns.

In your class - probably Movie (see where and how $myMovie was instantiated) you will find this add function. Check what it returns.

Comment: Here is the actual code:                                                          <? 
$myShape1=new SWFShape(); 

$myShape1->setLine(5,0,0,255); 

$myShape1->drawLine(440,0); 


$myMovie=new SWFMovie(); 

$myMovie->setDimension(460,80); 
$myMovie->setBackground(255,0,0); 

$firstLine=$myMovie->add($myShape1); 
$firstLine->moveTo(10,10); 

$secondLine=$myMovie->add($myShape1); 
$secondLine->moveTo(10,70); 

$myMovie->save("lesson2.swf"); 

?>

Comment: @appu you should put that code in your question (click edit and paste it there. In comments it gets unreadable)

Comment: @appu: go to SWFMovie Class and see what type is returned by the add function.

Answer (score 1):

From [PHP Manual](http://php.net/function.swfmovie.add):

> For displayable types (shape, text,
>   button, sprite), this returns an
>   SWFDisplayItem, a handle to the object
>   in a display list. Thus, you can add
>   the same shape to a movie multiple
>   times and get separate handles back
>   for each separate instance.

You can also use `var_dump($firstLine);` to see what it returns.

Comment: Here is what it returns object(SWFDisplayItem)[5]
  public 'displayitem' => resource(4, SWFDisplayItem)
I am sorry as am i not able to interpret it as it is mumbo jumbo to me since I am new to PHP.

Comment: So u mean $firstLine is a handle or a pointer/indicator to an object similar to $fp (file handle) for file operations in PHP  Am i right ?

Comment: Yeah, you can think that $firstLine is some kind of pointer to the object of class [SWFDisplayItem](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.swfdisplayitem.php)

Answer (score 0):

PHP does not have pointers as the C-like languages do. Instead — similarly to Java or C# — all instances of user-defined types are references. That means that if you do `$firstLine = $otherLine`, they are two references to the same data. In PHP you have to be explicit when you want to copy the actual data, not just the reference; see:
> http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.cloning.php

Answer (score 0):

The variable `$firstLine` will contain whatever the method `add` returns. For example if `add` returns `true`, then `$firstLine` will contain `true`.

Answer (score 0):

`$myMovie` is an [object](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.basic.php) that has a method (a fancy word for a function contained within a [class](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.basic.php)) named `add()`. `$firstLine` simply contains the value returned from that method.